# Failed to Create File. Second time it succeeds

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Sorry at first - for this problem it is completely impossible to create a a minimal example since some specialized hardware is involved.

So.. We have built a recording device that connects to the PC via USB and simulates a SD card in (shows up as a drive). The drive is initially read only
but can be toggled to read/write operations by writing to a special sector (between MBR and FAT) so files can be created on that drive.

So far so good. Now Windows seems to create some hickups when a file is created complaining that the media is read only. A second attempt to create the file actually succeeds.

Here is the code that es executed:

```
 if not (fMK5UsbComm as TMK5USBComm).IsWritable then
    raise Exception.Create('WTF');

 try
 fs:=TFileStream.Create(fMK5UsbComm.DriveLetter + ':\Tom24.ini', fmCreate   or fmOpenReadWrite);
 try
    fs.WriteBuffer(ss[1], length(ss));
 finally
        fs.Free;
 end;
 except
 fs:=TFileStream.Create(fMK5UsbComm.DriveLetter + ':\Tom24.ini', fmCreate   or fmOpenReadWrite);
 try
    fs.WriteBuffer(ss[1], length(ss));
 finally
        fs.Free;
 end;

 end;
```

IsWritable is defined as:

```
 function TVolume.IsWritable: boolean;
 var numBytesReturned : DWORD;
 begin
      numBytesReturned := 0;

      Result := DeviceIoControl( fHandle,
                                 IOCTLDiskIsWritable,
                                 nil,
                                 0,
                                 nil,
                                 0,
                                 numBytesReturned,
                                 nil);

      if not Result then
      begin
           if GetLastError <> ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT then
              RaiseLastOSError;
      end;
 end;
```

So the question is: Why is the second attempt successfull and the first filestream is not?

How could I convice Windows that the drive is actually not write protected?
I tried a few IO control codes:
IOCTLCheckVerify
IOCTLUpdateProperties

but without success.

I don't expect any code but some thoughts would be highly appreaciated.

A little clarification: 
fMK5UsbComm holds 2 handles: one to the volume and one to the physical device that is associated to the volume. The physcial device handle is opened read only first, the a special read operation takes place which undoes the read only flag in the device and then the handle is reopened read/write (to allow special communication with the device).

Comment: It's surely off topic because it can't be reproduced. And we can't see the relevant code. Which is quite possibly in the hardware or a device driver.

Comment: The problem actually also is that after removing the read only flag it is actually possible to copy a file in the explorer... but it fails in the program. And yes David I know you always want a minimal example but that's not possible... so I kindly asked for a few hints that might help

Comment: It's not me that wants that. It's site policy. This is the wrong place for such a question. Ask on G+ delphi devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I got it now - so this is just for anybody who may eventually fall into the same trap:

1. The drive handle was obtained by issuing the SYNCHRONIZED access flag instead of GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE. This speeds up detection of the device since it is not fully mounted at that time (e.g. reading the FAT which is slow on that device) but lower level calls are possible.
2. I needed to close the drive handle, reopen it with GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, issue a FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME command and then reopen the drive handle again which mounts the drive and let windows update the internal volume information.